# filepicker.io java intergration: base64 encoding does not give a vaid signature

Tags: java, base64, filepicker.io

I am trying to integrate filepicker.io (with security enabled) into our java application. 
In the java code I am generating the javascript for the filepicker integration, using the following code for base64 encoding:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

private Pair<String, String> encodeAndSignPolicy(Policy policy) {
   byte[] jsonPolicy = JSON_MAPPER.writeValueAsBytes(policy);
   String encodedPolicy = base64UrlEncode(jsonPolicy);

   byte[] signature = m_mac.doFinal(encodedPolicy.getBytes(UTF8));
   String encodedSignature = base64UrlEncode(signature);

   return Pair.create(encodedPolicy, encodedSignature);
}

private String base64UrlEncode(byte[] input) {
   Base64 base64 = new Base64(false);
   byte[] encodedBytes = base64.encode(input);
   return new String(encodedBytes).replace('+', '-').replace('/', '_').replace("\r\n", "");
}
```

In some cases this works, but it is not stable. I have tried different variations for url safe base64 encoding, including different api's (apache commons and jackson) but every time the generated signature is unstable.

For example: the two following policies are generated:

```
working:
policy: {"call":"pick","expiry":1361202256856} 
base64 policy: eyJjYWxsIjoicGljayIsImV4cGlyeSI6MTM2MTIwMjI1Njg1Nn0= 
base64 signature: 0vQdw1rcfoAYN0sv71OcGArHAF2jozLaaMGR2DZ5DbA= 

not working:
Policy: {"call":"pick","expiry":1361202299638} 
base64 policy: eyJjYWxsIjoicGljayIsImV4cGlyeSI6MTM2MTIwMjI5OTYzOH0= 
base64 signature: wzgaIRume9OZ5Q6TKx-c5LaEabmUmENZk0Dwvm0Y01Y=
```

and the generated javascript:

```
filepicker.pickMultiple({
        container: 'modal',
        openTo: 'GOOGLE_DRIVE',
        services:['BOX', 'COMPUTER', 'DROPBOX', 'EVERNOTE', 'FACEBOOK', 'FLICKR', 'FTP', 'GITHUB', 'GOOGLE_DRIVE', 'PICASA', 'WEBDAV', 'GMAIL', 'IMAGE_SEARCH', 'INSTAGRAM', 'URL', 'VIDEO', 'WEBCAM'],
        policy: 'eyJjYWxsIjoicGljayIsImV4cGlyeSI6MTM2MTIwMjI5OTYzOH0=',
        signature: 'wzgaIRume9OZ5Q6TKx-c5LaEabmUmENZk0Dwvm0Y01Y=',
    },
    function(FPFiles){
        $('#filePickerInput7c').val(JSON.stringify(FPFiles));
        $('#filePickerInput7c').change();
    },
    function(FPError){
        console.log(FPError.toString());
    }
);
```

It seems that every time the signature contains a '-' or '_' it is found to be invalid. How do i generate a valid signature (and policy) in java for filepicker.io?

Comment: Solved the problem: It seems filepicker.io does not accept the policy as base64 encoded, but it needs to be hexadecimal. The correct code to generate the encoded policy is now: 
String encodedSignature = new String(Hex.encodeHex(signature));